# Angular2 reverse/generate url from Routes (typescript)

Tags: url, angular, build, routes, reverse

How can I generate url from route be code?
For exemple, I have a login component in my routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    ...
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    ...
];
```

I want to build a string corresponding to the url of my login component:

```
let url = "I don't know";
console.log(url); ----> 'http:localhost:4200/login'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can inject `Router` and `UrlSerializer`

```
constructor(router: Router, urlSerializer: UrlSerializer, route: ActivatedRoute) {
  let tree = router.createUrlTree(['/path', param, 'otherPath'], { relativeTo: route, queryParams: {y: z} });
  let url = urlSerializer.serialize(tree);
}
```

When `router.createUrlTree` is given an activate route as above, it applies the given commands starting from the route. When not given a route, it applies the given command starting from the root.

To get the static part of the URL you might need to inject `Location` and use

```
let fullUrl = window.location.origin + location.prepareExternalUrl(url);
```

See also

- https://angular.io/api/router/Router
- https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer
- https://angular.io/api/common/Location
- https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras
- https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/klWlfI8QzfQ355Od68jd?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With this code, the full URL is '/login'. 
Why the domaine name isn't added ?
`let tree = router.createUrlTree(['login']); let url = urlSerializer.serialize(tree); let fullUrl = location.prepareExternalUrl(url);`

Comment: It still doesn't return the full url. It return `/path` :(

Comment: This code works: `let fullUrl = location.prepareExternalUrl(window.location.origin + url);`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. `window.location.origin + location.prepareExternalUrl(url)` worked for me (see Plunker)

Comment: Thanks @Jason for reviving my old answer :)

Comment: No worries @Günter!